# Using directive missing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm new using Sharepoint and I have a question. When I try to use this code:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
var myItems = '';
var i;

for (i in items)
{
myItems += '|' + items[i].id;
}
```

Get this:

> the type or namespace ClientContext name does not exist in the namespace
>   (are you missing an assembly reference)

Which reference or using sentence am I missing? Even when I type the SP and dot, there is nothing there that allows me to select a method or something. I use Visual Studio 2013 professional and SharePoint 2010. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet above is JavaScript code, you seem to need C# code. That's the root of your issues.

Search for CSOM examples instead of JSOM / JavaScript samples and you should be of to a good start

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look for CSOM examples to get the objects in a SharePoint List. Thanks again.

Comment: Try this link (section about list items, first example in that section): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks

Comment: Very useful !!! I got another question after see those examples: I have only one using directive (using Microsoft.Sharepoint;), do I have to add another?, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you writing a farm solution or something in an app? The code examples in the link is for an app, here as for classic server side code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms456030(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I'm writing a farm solution, i'll check the link. Thank you,